# Please help identify this medal... German military?

Tags: military, german

Found this in my late father's possessions. Probably belonged to his father or grandfather. Prussian? German? war related? I have no idea...[image: nothing on the back. looks like acorn/oak on target. green cross.]

Comment: Is there anything at all on the reverse side?

Comment: It appears to me that there might still be ribbon attached and hidden by your fingers. If so, that ribbon is an intrinsic part of the medal, whether military or not, and will make identification both easier and more definitive. Please advise

Comment: Very nice job on the quality high resolution image BTW.

Comment: nothing on the reverse side @LarsBosteen

Comment: no ribbon attached @PieterGeerkens

Answer (score 6):

This looks like one of the various marksmanship medals *(Schützenorden)* issued by many shooting clubs *(Schützenvereine)* in German-speaking countries.

Compare for example this [image search](https://www.google.com/search?q=Sch%C3%BCtzenorden+silber+gr%C3%BCn&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjW16flnNbfAhUBCiwKHdXsAisQ_AUIDigB&biw=1280&bih=895).

Comment: If that flower image in the centre is a stylized *edelweiss* I'd be checking shooting clubs in the Tyrol around Salzburg.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens These are oak-leaves and oak fruits in front of a marksman's target disk. That's pretty generic. The point you raised below the Q however might be important, a crown indicates a year's competition winner (obscured by fingers). Without more info from inscriptions (backside?) it's improbable to pinpoint. Just that's not real military.

Comment: @LangLangC: Ha ha! So right you are. I learned to distinguish white from black oak leaves at six, and should have spotted that myself. Acorns and oaks are a heraldic symbol of royalty however, so that might suggest a *royal* (as contrasted with mere *noble*) charter for the club. That suggests Berlin, Munich, Vienna as locales.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Not really, I guess. The leaves are just Germanic, and a woods symbol. But royal insofar The 'winner' of one such competition is called *king* of marksmen. Compare this description of [acorns to achievments](https://www.nwzonline.de/oldenburg-kreis/kultur/von-schuetzenorden-und-ihrer-bedeutung_a_30,0,3398400522.html) or this [catalog](https://www.nwzonline.de/oldenburg-kreis/kultur/von-schuetzenorden-und-ihrer-bedeutung_a_30,0,3398400522.html) or this [aficionado breast](https://www.vohwinkel.net/pics/ortsteile/osterholz/schuetzenfest/18004-schuetzenorden.jpg) from Lower Saxony

Comment: @LangLangC No date inscription anywhere. (and my father did live in the Berlin area for time).

Comment: @Tim So probably no "*spoils* of war"? You might want to add these dates (of life events) to focus on to your question. [I thought your (American?) soldier father brought a souvenir…] Every bit of context helps.

Comment: @LangLangC My father was probably too young to be a soldier in the German army, but his older brother was in it. (born '31, '29 respectively). He was an excellent shot apparently, so probably his medal. He left Berlin in 1950 (as a 19 yo) and migrated to Australia. There are other medals and badges I have, but I've already identified them (Prussian war medals, WWII German Uboat badge etc)